# Angular: How to get inside object data in the response?

Tags: angular

This is the data:

> [image: Response Data Screen Short]

I tried this way =>

```
this.result = res?.permissions?.action_findings.store;
```

Can you give me a proper answer?

Comment: `res?.permission?["action_findings.store"];`

Comment: core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'action_findings.store' of undefined

Comment: hmm there was a typo: it's `permissions`, not `permission`

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'action_findings.store' of undefined

Comment: shouldnt it be `res.data.permissions["action_findings.store"]` ? since im guessing the res is an api response and the log that you linked is a data object inside the response ?

Comment: I got result using res so we don't need data right?

Comment: Can you check this link. I upload image https://ibb.co/C6J1QGc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `?` operator with bracket `[]` you should write:

```
res?.permissions?.["action_findings.store"]
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/C6J1QGc

Comment: @Gowsegan post me an image of the `console.log(resp)`

Comment: https://ibb.co/Y7GM8cW

Comment: any corrections

Comment: @Gowsegan I can't find any error in your code... Lets make some debug together: if you try to `console.log(resp.created_at)` you see the correct date?